# using strlen in loop reversing a string in C

Tags: c, string

I'm trying to write a code where I input a String and I get it reversed. I.e.: "nokia" to "aikon".

I already have it in a way, but now I want to use the function `strlen()` to get the original String's length and create the new one based on that length.

Here is the code:

```
void main(void)
{
    char palavra[10];
    char palavra2[10];
    int i;
    int k;

    printf("Introduza uma string: \n");
    scanf("%[^\n]", palavra);

    for( i = 0, k = strlen(palavra) - 1 ; i <= k; i++, k--)
    {
        palavra2[k] = palavra[i];
    }
    printf("\nString invertida: %s", palavra2);
}
```

However all I get from my `printf()` is a "?". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note: `palavra2[k]` is not null character terminated.

Comment: `for( i = 0, k = strlen(palavra) - 1 ; i <= k; i++, k--)`   It is a real bad idea to use `k` in the `i <= k;` clause  and also do `k--`  You are effectively only writing the second half of the string, without the null at the end too.

Comment: why not use `strrev`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this simple reverse function:

```
/* reverse:  reverse string s in place */
void reverse(char s[])
{
    int c, i, j;

    for (i = 0, j = strlen(s)-1; i < j; i++, j--) {
        c = s[i];
        s[i] = s[j];
        s[j] = c;
    }
}
```

To integrate it into your code:

```
void main(void)
{
    char palavra[10];
    int c, i, j;

    /* read the string */
    printf("Introduza uma string: \n");
    scanf("%[^\n]", palavra);

    /* null-terminate the string */
    palavra[strlen(palavra)] = '\0';

    /* reverse the string */
    for (i = 0, j = strlen(palavra)-1; i < j; i++, j--) {
        c = palavra[i];
        palavra[i] = palavra[j];
        palavra[j] = c;
    }

    printf("\nString invertida: %s", palavra);
}
```

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Huh; too bad I'm out of votes, otherwise I'd upvote the question and your answer to encourage more voters...

Comment: don't worry for me. Ah your downvote got cleared. I wouldn't upvote the question BTW. It's reproducible but not very good: using a debugger or printf would be enough to understand what's going on. I did that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129845/discussion-between-md-xf-and-jean-francois-fabre).

Comment: I downvoted this just now because it's a code-only answer.

Comment: @immibis Does that mean that if I add information you'll reverse the vote?

Comment: Note that `reverse("")` results `j = (size_t)0 -1;` and   "either the result is implementation-deﬁned or an implementation-deﬁned signal is raised."

Comment: I upvoted the answer. I don't see anything wrong with it.

Answer (score 7):

your loop indexes are running the opposite ways so they meet in the middle and the loop stops when `i <= k`: half of the string is not inverted. Just test `i` against `strlen(palavra)`

Plus you have to null-terminate your string:

```
int len=strlen(palavra);
for( i = 0, k = len - 1 ; i < len; i++, k--)
{
    palavra2[k] = palavra[i];
}
palavra2[len]='\0';
```

(and you'd better store the value of `strlen(palavra)` so you have to compute it only once)

Answer (score 1):

The above answer are quite good , Iam just enhancing code by optimized it using bit operation.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)

{
    char palavra[10];

    printf("Introduza uma string: \n");
    scanf("%[^\n]", palavra);

    char *start=palavra;
    int len = strlen(palavra);
    char *end = (palavra+len-1);

    while(start < end )
    {
            *start = *start ^ *end;
            *end = *end ^ *start;
            *start = *end ^ *start;
            start++;
            end--;

    }


printf("\nString invertida: %s\n", palavra);

return 0;
}
```

It is good to use Bitwise operator and reducing number of iteration by half , inplace swapping

Answer (score -1):

You can use recursive function. I am using string class (specific to C++), you can change it to char*.

```
void reverse(string& str, int i, int len)
{
    if(i<len)
        reverse(str, i+1, len-1);
    swap(str[i], str[len]);
}
```

Caller - `reverse(str, 0, str.length()-1)`